# .NET core JWT validation with Azure B2C

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a problem with a token validation against `Azure B2C`. The error is:

> AuthenticationFailed: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer:
>   '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in
>   IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. Did not match:
>   validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the
>   'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'
>   or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden by default. Set
>   the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal
>   it.]'.

In my `.net core` `webapi` project, I added **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** from Nuget. Then in the *Startup.cs* under `ConfigureServices` I added:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  { 
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
  {
    jwtOptions.Authority = 
         $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["B2CTenantId"]}/" + 
         "{Configuration["B2CPolicy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["B2CClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
  });

  private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext arg)
  {
        // For debugging purposes only!
        var s = $"AuthenticationFailed: {arg.Exception.Message}";
        arg.Response.ContentLength = s.Length;
        arg.Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s), 0, s.Length);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
  }
```

where `B2CTenandId` is similar to `mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`, `B2CClientId` is the if from Azure Portal and `B2CPolicy` is `b2c_1_susi` (created for the login).

[image: Azure B2C configuration]

Comment: AFAIK, the url should be `$"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["B2CTenantId"]}/v2.0";`

Comment: Under `Token compatibility settings` there is the url I'm using

Comment: That's the issuer, not the authority

Comment: The right connection is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["B2CTenantId"]}/B2C_1_susi/v2.0/`

Answer (score 2):

The right configuration is

```
var cnn = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["B2CTenantId"]}/" +
          $"{Configuration["B2CPolicy"]}/v2.0/";
```

`B2CTenant` is your domain like `mydomain.onmicrosoft.com`.
`B2CPolicy` is the policy you created in `Azure Portal` (see my image in the question).

Comment: You could  get the detail steps from this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi).